# Syntax error using for x in range

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a simple program that creates 100 words using probs.generate with for x in range (0,99), however im getting a syntax error at at for and i don't get why

```
x = probs.generate()
Instance = for x in range (0, 99)
print " ".join(Instance)
```

where probs is defined as:

```
raw_data = "This is a very short text. It is used as a test."
allwords = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_data)
freq = nltk.FreqDist(allwords)
probs = nltk.MLEProbDist(freq)
```

and then im trying to connect the words in a list afterwards. I'm also somewhat new to python so sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: What is that for supposed to be doing? You need a : at the end if you want to use it as an imperative loop, or wrap it in brackets to use as a generator/comprehension. Neither of those options seems to make sense in this context though.

Comment: When you are using `x in range()` that means you are iterating through all x from 0 to 99, because range() returns you a list of values http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/ . If you want to iterate through probs.generate() you need to write something like `for x in probs.generate()`

Comment: I was trying to make it generate a word a hundred times, or have i misunderstood how for x in range (0, 99) works?

Comment: then you should do : `[x for i in range(0, 99)]` @Levicia

Comment: this will however still give me a syntax error pointing at the "r" in for :/

Comment: `[probs.generate() for _ in range(0, 99)]` may be what you're looking for

Comment: the suggestion made the syntax error disappear, instead i get a new syntax error after the second " in my print? :/

Comment: @Levicia, if you are getting a new syntax error after the second `"` in your print statement, there may be an error before the print statement. try commenting out the print line and all lines below the print (put `#` at the start of the line). Run the script again and find which line has the syntax error. ***Or*** [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46917810/edit) your question and put your current code, then we can try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what your generate() method does, so I substituted it with a mock, and it works.

```
def generate():
  return "x"

x = [generate() for i in range(0, 99)]
print (" ".join(x))
```

So you need to replace generate() to probs.generate()

You can play around with it here https://repl.it/NKAr/1

Comment: Seems you were using Python 3.x which requires brackets for print function, that's why you had the error with ' " ', check your Python's version and be careful with the difference in syntax between Python 3.x and Python 2.x